How to make such a structure for cpt?
How to make such a structure for cpt?
'/slug/%category%/%category2%/%postname%/' for post
'/slug/%category1%/%category2%/' for taxonomy
There will be a maximum of 2 levels of categories.
If a post has one category then '/slug/%category%/%postname%/'
I need this kind of structure only for this CPT and Taxonomy.
    register_post_type(
'slug_cpt',
 array(
 'labels'              => $labels,
 'exclude_from_search' => false,
'has_archive'         => true,
'public'              => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'rewrite'  => true,
'can_export'          => true,
'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
'supports'            => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'page-attributes', 'custom-fields'),
'show_in_rest' =>true,
 )
);
register_taxonomy(
'slug_cats',
'slug_cpt',
 array(
 'hierarchical'      => true,
 'show_admin_column' => true,
 'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
 'labels'            =>array(),
 'query_var'         => true,
 'show_in_rest' => true,
    )
  );


If you use the Advanced Custom Fields plugin (ACF) to create your custom taxonomy for your custom post type then you can just check the box to make it hierarchical. It will then automatically create a url structure matching the hierarchy.
